# A problem when use ALE for syntax checking and gvim for vivado's editor

Tags: gvim, microsoft-windows, plugin-ale

**VIM version**:

VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Sep 14 2020 22:03:16)

**OS information**:

Microsoft Windows 10 Professional version 2004 (OS Version: 10.0.19041)

### Problem Description:

I use gvim as text editor for vivado.

[image: vivado setting capture]

In Vivado, I click the verilog source file, the gvim will open the verilog file. And I use ALE for syntax checking. Everything else works, except the `include` statement.

For example:

There are one verilog file ( FileA.v ) and one verilog headerfile ( FileB.vh ) in the theme directory. In FileA.v, I use `include`:

```
`include "FileB.vh"
```

when I click FileA.v in Vivado, gvim is called to open FileA.v, then a syntax error will be reported:

```
[VRFC 10-3195] cannot open include file 'FileB.vh'
```

In fact, since FileA.v and FileB.vh is in the same directory, there should be no syntax error. And what puzzles me is that, at this time, resave this file by `:w`, the error will disappear.

However, close the opened file and click FileA.v in Vivado again, the problem occurs again.

Here is my _vimrc

```
set nocompatible
set nobackup
set noswapfile
set history=1024
set autochdir
set whichwrap=b,s,<,>,[,]
set nobomb
set backspace=indent,eol,start whichwrap+=<,>,[,]

set clipboard+=unnamed

set winaltkeys=no

set fileencodings=utf-8,gbk2312,gbk,gb18030,cp936
set encoding=utf-8
set langmenu=zh_CN
let $LANG = 'en_US.UTF-8'

colorscheme smyck

source $VIMRUNTIME/delmenu.vim
source $VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim
set cursorline
set hlsearch
set number

set lines=35 columns=140

set splitbelow
set splitright

set guioptions-=T
set guioptions-=m
set guioptions-=L
" set guioptions-=r
set guioptions-=b

set guioptions-=e
set nolist
" set listchars=tab:▶\ ,eol:¬,trail:·,extends:>,precedes:<
set guifont=Consolas:h12:cANSI

set autoindent
set smartindent
set tabstop=4
set expandtab
set softtabstop=4
syntax on

au BufRead,BufNewFile *.vh set filetype=verilog


" Plugins
execute pathogen#infect()

let g:airline#extensions#ale#enabled = 1

" Airline
let g:airline_theme='papercolor'
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I see you have `set autochdir` in your vimrc. That setting often doesn't play well with plug-ins (though in this case one might think it could actually help...) Did you try disabling this option and see whether that helps?

Comment: @filbranden Thanks for your reply. if disable `set autochdir`, this error will always exist, even after using `:w`. So I think I can understand why this error occurs. By `:ALEInfo` I find ale copy current file to a temporary directory, and Vivado's syntax checker `xvlog` work in this temporary directory, of course it can not find the include file. I think ale's work directory should change to the file directory. I'm new to vim, I don't how to do.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.

For example:

I open Vivado at `D:\Vivado_Projects\WorkSpace`, when I click to open verilog source file in gvim, execute `:cd`, then I get `D:\Vivado_Projects\WorkSpace`, so there if include error.

If enable `set autochdir`, the work directory will change to file location, then include error will disappear after using `:w`.

Finally I write a batch file to launch gvim:

```
@echo off

set /a cnt=0

:loop
set /a cnt+=1
for /f tokens^=%cnt%^ delims^=^"\/ %%i in (%1) do (
    if not "%%i"=="" (
        set A=%A%%%i\
        set B=%A%
        goto loop
    ) 
)

cd /d %B%
gvim %1 +%2
```

Vivado Custom Editor Definition:

```
"path/to/gvim_for_vivado.cmd" [file name] [line number]
```